# Tab Colors in a DockPanel using WeiFen Luo's DockPanelSuite

Tags: c#, dockpanel

I'm totally new with dockPanel and dockContent in c#, but I'm using WeiFen Luo's DockPanelSuite and I have a dockPanel which display forms by docking. the question is, how can I change the color of the tab of every form (dockContent)?

I saw that I can change the color using:

```
lContent.DockHandler.DockPanel.Skin.DockPaneStripSkin.DocumentGradient.InactiveTabGradient.StartColor = lColor;
lContent.DockHandler.DockPanel.Skin.DockPaneStripSkin.DocumentGradient.ActiveTabGradient.StartColor = lColor;
lContent.DockHandler.DockPanel.Skin.DockPaneStripSkin.DocumentGradient.InactiveTabGradient.EndColor = lColor;
lContent.DockHandler.DockPanel.Skin.DockPaneStripSkin.DocumentGradient.ActiveTabGradient.EndColor = lColor;
```

*lColor is a random Color that I'm getting with another function.
but those lines change the color to all the tags to the same color, and what I want is to change to different color to every tab.

[Example of Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saXI9.png)